# how to use 'requests' to login the website such as giffgaff.com

Tags: python, python-requests

How to login the website "giffgaff.com" by using python requests?

I tried all basic ways but doesn't work, here is my code:

```
import requests
import bs4

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get("https://www.giffgaff.com/auth/login")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
token = soup.select("#login_security_token")[0]['value']
print token
login_form = {
    "redirect": "",
    "p_next_page": "",
    "nickname": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "submit_button": "Login",
    "login_security_token": token
}
r = s.post("https://www.giffgaff.com/auth/login", data=login_form)
print r.text
```

Could anybody give me some tested code?

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with 'doesn't work?' Do you get an exception? Different output than you expected?

Comment: @WanderNauta I mean the login failed, it will stay in login page.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been working on this myself.
Your code would work, but it is sending too many cookies. giffgaff set 3 cookies that start with ___, they are all set to expire in the past. If you remove them it will work.

```
for cookie in session.cookies.keys():
    if cookie.startswith('___'):
        del session.cookies[cookie]
```

working code posted here: https://github.com/mattvenn/python/tree/master/giffgaff